# java minecraft texture with modded block not working

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I decided to start learning java and make a minecraft mod. I tried to make an modded block with holes and extensions  but when I try to start minecraft it says that there is something wrong with the texture.

terminal error:
Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.TextureStitchEvent$Post to a broken mod state java

Minecraft error:
mods.toml missing metadata for modid forge

this is my code from my core "Cosmicages.java":

```
package quintoniusvlint.cosmicages;

import com.mojang.logging.LogUtils;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Blocks;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.event.RegistryEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.IEventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.InterModComms;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLCommonSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.InterModEnqueueEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.InterModProcessEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.server.ServerStartingEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import quintoniusvlint.cosmicages.core.ModBlocks;
import quintoniusvlint.cosmicages.core.ModItems;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static net.minecraftforge.versions.forge.ForgeVersion.MOD_ID;

// The value here should match an entry in the META-INF/mods.toml file
@Mod(MOD_ID)
public class Cosmicages {

    // Directly reference a slf4j logger
    public static final String MOD_ID = "cosmicages";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogUtils.getLogger();

    public Cosmicages() {
        IEventBus bus = FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus();
        bus.addListener(this::setup);
        bus.addListener(this::enqueueIMC);
        bus.addListener(this::processIMC);
        ModBlocks.BLOCKS.register(bus);
        ModItems.ITEMS.register(bus);
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
    }

    private void setup(final FMLCommonSetupEvent event) {
        // Some preinit code
        LOGGER.info("HELLO FROM PREINIT");
        LOGGER.info("DIRT BLOCK >> {}", Blocks.DIRT.getRegistryName());
    }

    private void enqueueIMC(final InterModEnqueueEvent event) {
        // Some example code to dispatch IMC to another mod
        InterModComms.sendTo("cosmicages", "helloworld", () -> {
            LOGGER.info("Hello world from the MDK");
            return "Hello world";
        });
    }

    private void processIMC(final InterModProcessEvent event) {
        // Some example code to receive and process InterModComms from other mods
        LOGGER.info("Got IMC {}", event.getIMCStream().
                map(m -> m.messageSupplier().get()).
                collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    // You can use SubscribeEvent and let the Event Bus discover methods to call
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onServerStarting(ServerStartingEvent event) {
        // Do something when the server starts
        LOGGER.info("HELLO from server starting");
    }

    // You can use EventBusSubscriber to automatically subscribe events on the contained class (this is subscribing to the MOD
    // Event bus for receiving Registry Events)
    @Mod.EventBusSubscriber(bus = Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus.MOD)
    public static class RegistryEvents {
        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void onBlocksRegistry(final RegistryEvent.Register<Block> blockRegistryEvent) {
            // Register a new block here
            LOGGER.info("HELLO from Register Block");
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code from my core "ModBlocks":

```
package quintoniusvlint.cosmicages.core;

import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.state.BlockBehaviour;
import net.minecraft.world.level.material.Material;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.RegistryObject;
import quintoniusvlint.cosmicages.Cosmicages;

public class ModBlocks {

    public static final DeferredRegister<Block> BLOCKS = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.BLOCKS, Cosmicages.MOD_ID);

    public static final RegistryObject<Block> ARTIFACT_BLOCK = BLOCKS.register("artifact_block", () -> new Block(BlockBehaviour.Properties.of(Material.STONE)));
}
```

this is my code from my core "ModItems":

```
package quintoniusvlint.cosmicages.core;

import net.minecraft.world.item.BlockItem;
import net.minecraft.world.item.CreativeModeTab;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.RegistryObject;
import quintoniusvlint.cosmicages.Cosmicages;

public class ModItems {
    public static final DeferredRegister<Item> ITEMS = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS, Cosmicages.MOD_ID);

    public static final RegistryObject<Item> ARTIFACT_BLOCK = ITEMS.register("ARTIFACT_BLOCK", () -> new BlockItem(ModBlocks.ARTIFACT_BLOCK.get(), new Item.Properties().tab(CreativeModeTab.TAB_BUILDING_BLOCKS)));
}
```

this is my code from my "blockstates/artifact_block.json":

```
{
    "variants": {
        "": {"model": "cosmicages:block/artifact_block"}
    },
    "credit": "Made with Blockbench",
    "parent": "ArtifactActivationBlock",
    "texture_size": [128, 128],
    "textures": {
        "0": "block/ texture"
    },
    "elements": [
        {
{
    "variants": {
        "": {"model": "cosmicages:block/artifact_block"}
    },
    "credit": "Made with Blockbench",
    "parent": "ArtifactActivationBlock",
    "texture_size": [128, 128],
    "textures": {
        "0": "block/ texture"
    },
    "elements": [
        {
            //and then we have the position of the block etc
```

this is my code from my "models/block/artifact_block.json":

```
{
    "credit": "Made with Blockbench",
    "parent": "block/cube_all",
    "texture_size": [128, 128],
    "textures": {
        "all": "cosmicages:block/artifact_block"
    },
    "elements": [
        {
            //and then we have the position of the block etc
```

this is my code from my "models/item/artifact_block.json":

```
{
    "credit": "Made with Blockbench",
    "parent": "cosmicages:block/artifact_block",
    "texture_size": [128, 128],
    "textures": {
        "0": "block/texture"
    },
    "elements": [
        {
            //and then we have the position of the block etc
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to render a transparent block. the problem might be in the json file.

I use mcreator for my mods and i found this in this directory: models/block/artifact_block.json:

```
{
   "parent": "cosmicages:block/artifact_block",
   "textures": {
       "all": "cosmicages:block/artifact_block",
       "particle": "cosmicages:block/artifact_block"
   },
   "render_type": "solid"
}
```

i found something called render type. I went in the transparency type and here are all the possible options:

- "solid" - Instead of transparency it's black in the transparent spots
- "cutout" - normal non opaque rendering with alpha check
- "cutout_mipped" - the same thing as cutout + a minimap is generated
  for better graphic on big distances
- "translucent" - fully transparent

all of those options was according to my research on the internet and don't know if it's accurate